# Daily running total for each month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table with daily count data, which looks something like this:

```
Date         Count
2019-12-01     100
2019-12-02     200
2019-12-03     300
...            ...
2020-01-01      10
2020-01-02     200
2020-01-03     500
```

I am trying to compute the running total on a daily basis **for each** month. The desired result should look like this:

```
Date         Count    Running Total
2019-12-01     100              100
2019-12-02     200              300
2019-12-03     300              600
...            ...
2020-01-01      10               10
2020-01-02     200              210
2020-01-03     500              710
...
```

I managed to compute a running total for a single month, however I am struggling to get the running totals for multiple months with a single query. Anyone knows how to do or can provide an idea to do it only using SQL? I am running MySQL 5.7.

Best

Comment: it's easier to compute within DB ver.8. Consider upgrading.

Comment: I am using MySQL on Google Cloud - Version 8 is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Session variables like

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`Date` date, `Count` int)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`Date`, `Count`)
> VALUES
>     ('2019-12-01', 100),
>     ('2019-12-02', 200),
>     ('2019-12-03', 300),
>     ('2020-01-01', 10),
>     ('2020-01-02', 200),
>     ('2020-01-03', 500)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   `Date`
>   , `Count`
>   ,running_coint
> FROM
> (SELECT 
>   `Date`
>   , `Count`
>   , IF(MONTH(@date) =  MONTH(`Date`),@running_coint := @running_coint + `Count`,@running_coint := `Count`) running_coint
> ,  @date := `Date`
> FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY `Date`) t,(SELECT @running_coint := 0) a,(SELECT @date := '1999-01-01') b) t1
> ORDER BY`Date`;
> ```
>
> ```
> Date       | Count | running_coint
> :--------- | ----: | ------------:
> 2019-12-01 |   100 |           100
> 2019-12-02 |   200 |           300
> 2019-12-03 |   300 |           600
> 2020-01-01 |    10 |            10
> 2020-01-02 |   200 |           210
> 2020-01-03 |   500 |           710
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d8637f939f2d2c2f6b4d738b6e8d8258)*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Count) AS "Total count" FROM your_table WHERE Date < '2019-12-01';
```

Obviously the date would be whatever you want to check on.